# Create a Hierarchy Diagram from Python Code

Tags: python, hierarchy, diagram

I have got a project with a bunch of modules, and I was looking to create a hierarchy diagram automatically. Is there any way to do this? I created UML diagrams with pyreverse, but could not generate Function Hierarchy Diagrams.

[image]

Comment: Could you give an example of a "Function Hierarchy Diagram"?

Comment: @AKX I have updated, sorry for being vague

Comment: If you're looking for a library to do this, that is off topic here. If you think an existing library should be able to handle it (i.e., you're trying to figure out how to use the library, or adapt some existing code) then we will need a lot more specifics in order to have a properly answerable question. Please read [ask] and [mre].

Comment: If there's no library to do that yet, you could (try to) write your own with the `ast` or `libcst` modules.

Comment: would a callgraph suit your needs? if so, try pyan https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13963321/build-a-call-graph-in-python-including-modules-and-functions